# Bookmark kids to parent

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm trying to show an error while fetching dead bookmark links, written recursive function to traverse through kids and main bookmarks, I can trace the dead bookmark, but I would like to show the parent title as error to the user. Hope it is possible`? But I'm not sure, how to reach that.

```vb
Private Sub bookmarkGlobalSetting(ByRef bookRoot As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object)))

    For bk = bookRoot.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        'For Each bkMarkObj As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In bookmarks
        Dim bkMarkObj As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = bookRoot.Item(bk)
        Dim currentText As String = ""

        For bkInner = bkMarkObj.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1

            Dim bkKV As String = bkMarkObj.ElementAt(bkInner).Key

            If bkKV = "Named" Then
                If Not namedDestinationTargets.ContainsKey(bkMarkObj.Item(bkKV)) Then
                    '<here> instead of child title, can i get parent title
                    mstrErrorReport &= "Bookmark error - " & bkMarkObj.Item("Title") & " - Named destination wrong" & vbCrLf
                End If
            ElseIf bkKV = "Kids" Then
                bookmarkGlobalSetting(bkMarkObj.Item(bkKV))
            End If

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you just pass the parent in the recursion? Make it an optional second parameter that the initial caller doesn't use but internally the parent is always passed?

Comment: Children, not kids. Also please use something else instead of a "dead" bookmark. A screenshot could help explain what you want in the above.